# How to refresh my all instaces of an activity

Tags: android

I am facing an issue

```
I open Activity A there is some settings --> Go to Activity B ---> 
Go to Activity A ---> Change some settings in activity A ---> Go to Acivity C
```

In this case If I go back from Activity C I am getting latest setting If I go back I am again I am getting Activity B and again if I go back I am getting Activity A. But in this activity A I am getting the old settings.

How to get latest settings in Activity A here also. Is there any way if i make any change in any activity then if any instances of that activity is open those will get the latest data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences` to save any kind of data you may need after going back to an activity. Just load the data in activity's `onResume()` - this is the best way to not lose useful data. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,activityB);
```

go to activityB

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,activityA);//recall activityA
```

go to activityA

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,activityC);
```

to pass data you can use

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putInt("hello",3);

myIntent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

use recreate () in activity A before starting other activity